# Select until condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    EvType INT NOT NULL,
    CreatedByUserId INT NOT NULL
)
```

Initial data:

[image]

And i wonna get only rows which meet the next condition: We select row until Id of the row will be less than first row with EvType == 200 per createdByUserId. So we need to select firsly all first rows for each user with evType == 200, which i've done in this way:

```
WITH EVS1 AS (
SELECT evs.Id, evs.EvType, evs.CreatedByUserId
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY evs.CreatedByUserId ORDER BY evs.CreatedDate DESC) as rk
FROM [dbo].Table1 evs)

select *
From EVS1
WHERE EVS1.rk=1
```

Which produces the following result:

[image]

And then somehow i need to select rows for each user until Id is greater then row from CTE for that user, Is that possible to do that?

So we need to retrieve from that table rows until 4th included. Skip the 5th row cause it goes after the first user row with evType 200

Expected Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `min(id)` first and then the row having lower or equal `id`

```
SELECT *
FROM EVS1
WHERE id <= (SELECT MIN(id) FROM EVS1 WHERE evType = 200)
```

I assume that you define the ordering according to the `id` attribute.

If it is necessary to do it for each `CreatedByUserId` then use a dependent subquery for the minimal id computation

```
SELECT *
FROM EVS1 e1
WHERE id <= (
  SELECT MIN(id) 
  FROM EVS1 e2
  WHERE e2.evType = 200 
    and e1.CreatedByUserId = e2.CreatedByUserId
)
```

[**DBFIDDLE DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=635de117e552afdd1b0cbd54cbb99c0f)

I believe that this solution will be faster then a window function for a large data if you will have an index

```
CREATE INDEX ix_evs1_evType_CreatedByUserId ON evs1(evType, CreatedByUserId) INCLUDE(id)
```

Comment: Agree, don't really need a CTE for something like this

Comment: @RadimBača Results of second to last query gives me this one

Comment: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: But it is a subquery! Did you rewrite my query somehow?

Comment: @IRCodder https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=635de117e552afdd1b0cbd54cbb99c0f

Answer (score 0):

You can do a window max:

```
select Id, EvType, CreatedByUserId
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        max(case when EvType = 200 then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by CreatedByUserId order by Id) flagEvType
    from [dbo].Table1
)
where flagEvType = 0
```

Comment: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference

Comment: @IRCodder: there is not aggregate here, this is a window function. Please run the query exactly as provided.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select all rows created by a user except for those where an event type 200 occurred before:

```
select *
from mytable t1
where not exists
(
  select null
  from mytable t2
  where t2.evtype = 200
  and t2.createdbyuserid = t1.createdbyuserid
  and t2.id < t1.id
);
```